# Data Display in different width using PyCharm

Tags: python, excel, pycharm

I am new to Python and Pycharm. I imported an excel file, but when I print it, the width of the display is different than the display of another list.Why does it happen? How can I enlarge the display width?

Here is the display of the IDE:

[image: here is the display of the IDE].

Answer (score 0):

to show the whole df try this:

`pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)`

Comment: unfortunately, I still have the same display. The data that I imported from excel seem narrow while other lists have full width.